# restrict the execution of a function gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

In build.gradle of a project, I have many tasks, Now I'm building a new task which will take data related to project like sonar coverage report etc., create the report and upload it on the confluence.

1. The task called confluence is implemented by using markdown-confluence-gradle-plugin:0.6 [the implementation of the plugin can be found here](https://github.com/qwazer/markdown-confluence-gradle-plugin) which works fine, uploads the data to the confluence.
2. Now to get the data for e.g. Test coverage from sonar server, I'm writing a function which will hit the sonar server and get the figures and return to a variable in task confluence (mentioned in the point 1, the caller of the function).

```
def func1(){

// call to a sonar server 

}
```

The problem is when I build the project in intellij, it try to execute code in a function and so request the sonar server. What I'm trying to achieve is the code on function should not get executed when I build the project. But at that time when I call the task confluence explicitly to run.

Why code gets executed at the time of building the application, even though I have not called it for execution. It is just defined in build.gradle

I tried using doLast and finalizedBy for confluence task but it didn't work for this task. Implementation of the pugin can be found at a mentioned location above in the question.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you want to achieve. Gradle does implement nearly all actions in tasks, why do you want to use functions? Why can't you use `doFirst`/`doLast` closures?

Comment: @lu.koerfer I have updated the question, hope you get the it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want exclude your task from being run during build time and only run when you click on it right?

If this is the case you can use
 `gradlew build -x yourTaskName` 
from the command line (on windows) 
or include
 `yourTaskName.enabled = false` 
in your app level build.gradle.
Hope this helps.